# Solr - Achieve Delta-Import with the FileListEntityProcessor for PDF Files

Tags: pdf, solr, solrnet, dataimporthandler

Solr version :: 6.6.1

I am using the solr to index the PDF files and it is working fine as
expected. Now i have a requirement to perform the option of delta-import on
the the PDF files. Files which are added recently into the folder should only be processed during the data-import-handler action.

I am not able to locate the example of implementing the delta-import with
**FileListEntityProcessor**.

Please suggest.

*data-config.xml* file looks like this one.

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="BinFileDataSource"/>
  <document>
    <entity name="K1FileEntity" processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
dataSource="null"
            recursive = "true"
            baseDir="\\CLD02\RemoteDepot"
            fileName=".*pdf" rootEntity="false">

            <field column="file" name="id"/>
            <!--<field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="path" />
            <field column="fileSize" name="size" />-->
            <field column="fileLastModified" name="lastmodified" />

              <entity name="pdf" processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
onError="skip"
                      url="${K1FileEntity.fileAbsolutePath}" format="text">

                <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>
                <field column="dc:format" name="format" meta="true"/>
                <field column="text" name="text"/>

              </entity>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [in the docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler):

> delta-import
>
> For incremental imports and change detection. Only the
>   SqlEntityProcessor supports delta imports.

So you would need to either:

- move to indexing with some java code (using Solrj) and rolling your own delta import infra
- or implement all delta stuff for FileListEntityProcessor (and hopefully push it into Solr), you can use SqlEntityProcessor code as your guide.

Comment: Even i read that info too in the documentation. It seems strange there is no way to perform the delta-import for the PDF or other file types.

Comment: I also came across another property at the entity level by the name of newerThan="'NOW-3DAYS'". Can we utilized this one in a manner to achieve the delta-import ?

Comment: check http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/dataimporter-last-index-time-as-an-argument-to-newerThan-in-FileListEntityProcessor-td502311.html But be aware this is not full delta query, what about deleted files??

Comment: For deleted files , it should remove its index from the Solr core.. And i guess that is not happening for delta-query..